# React JS || When the email already exists Firebase give me this Error: (auth/missing-email)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

Please help me, I entered this code below but It doesn't work. When I give the correct email and password I get the error message ->

[image: screenshot of this error]

Here is my code:

```
const loginUser = (email, password, location, history) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(() => {
      const destination = location?.state?.from || "/";
      history.replace(destination);
      setError("");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setError(error.message);
    })
    .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
};
```

Comment: can you log the value of `email` before `signInWithEmailAndPassword`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes, I can, But it gives undefine value... Can you please help me...